# Content-Type as Json is not recognise in Slim Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, slim

```php
$searchApp = new \Slim\Slim();

$requestedFrom = 'header'

$searchApp->get('/', function () use ($searchApp, $requestedFrom) {

    $get = $searchApp->request()->get();

    if (sizeof($get) === 0 || strlen($get["q"]) === 0) {
        $searchApp->response()->body(json_encode("{}"));
        $searchApp->response()->status(400);
        $searchApp->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/JSON');

    } else {

        if ($requestedFrom !== null) {
            require "../V1.php";
        } else {
            require "../V0.php";
        }
    }
});

$searchApp->run();
```

then in V1.php i am writing

```php
$searchApp = new \Slim\Slim();

$response = $searchApp->response();

$searchApp->get('/', function () use ($searchApp, $out, $response) {
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $response->body(json_encode($out));
    $response->status(200);   
    //echo '{"foo":"bar"}';
});

$searchApp->run();
```

I even tried sending (echo '{"foo":"bar"}';) in body still that was also not recognized as JSON, it simply recognize all my request as text/html

I even tried setting global content-type using slim's object, but that too didn't worked in my case, i even tried adding charset after application/JSON;charset=utf-8 and even after removing it, it does'nt seems to work.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: i fix this issue, anyways thanks.

Comment: If so please give your solution as answer for other users with this problem.